# Response.Redirect(" ") OR window.location=" "

Tags: javascript, c#, http, redirect, http-redirect

What is the difference between the below methods?

**C#:**

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.microsoft.com/gohere/look.htm");
```

---

**Javascript:**

```
window.location='http://www.microsoft.com/gohere/look.htm'
```

**My question in another language**
In which cases it's better to use javascript redirection and in which cases it's better to use C# redirection?

Answer (score 2):

The first (C#) is issued by the server while it is processing a request and causes a Location header to be written into the response. The client, when it receives the response, can then decide whether to navigate to the URL specified in the header. Browsers are generally programmed to do so automatically, other HTTP clients may or may not do.

The second is a command issued from JavaScript code running in a web page, instructing the browser directly to navigate to a new URL.